# Do some numbers appear more frequently in the solution to equations?

Tags: number-theory

If we were to consider all possible equations, would we find that some numbers (perhaps pi and e) would more frequently be present in the solution to these equations than other numbers? Or do all numbers have equal likelihood at being in the solution to an equation?

Comment: What do you understand by an equation? Are several indeterminates allowed? Several equations with indeterminates?

Comment: Benford's law might be relevant here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law

Comment: What kind of equations?  How are you counting them?  If the equations are algebraic, the solutions are algebraic numbers, so never $\pi$ or $e$.

Comment: What is "all possible equations"? That's infinitely many, and our brains are not made to deal with infinities. Maybe the probability of any particular number is 0, so there is nothing to compare.

Comment: Thanks so much for your responses everyone. I've realized that my question isn't a very insightful one so I appreciate you still trying to help out. Benford's Law looks interesting. Cheers!